# irp processing and windows message generating

Tags: windows, keyboard, driver, wdm

I' m new in drivers. So excuse me for possible inaccuracies.

msdn such as some books about driver design give our some directions how to use wdm api. But i can find some literature or recources where i could get solid description of converting isr to final windows message.

for example we have keyboard. and device interrupt raised. I/O manager create irp and start to pass it downward along driver stack. every filter or functional driver can modify irp which they have just recieved. But what sould to be happened in the end of this process. But what layer or driver get some kind of parsed irp, transform it to windows message and put into input queue of OS?

Comment: This is internal to Windows and quite invisible.

Answer (score 4):

[Raw input thread (data received from the driver)](http://www.securelist.com/en/analysis/204792178/Keyloggers_Implementing_keyloggers_in_Windows_Part_Two#10):
[image]

Overview of how Windows processes keyboard input:

[image]

[Keyboard Input Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Keyboard_Input_Model):

[image]

Comment: good scheme. thanx.
but does it mean that to simulate keystroke it is enough to create irp in for example in upper level filter driver for i8042 and send this irp down to stack using IoCallDriver?